# What does "c/f" mean in a hospital discharge summary?

Tags: terminology

I'm reading a discharge summary received from a hospital and cannot decipher the "c/f" abbreviation. Here is the text:

> given c/f possible hepatic encephalopathy, started lactulose

I put "cf medical abbreviation" into my favorite search engine, but all I could find was cystic fibrosis which doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: I'm honestly surprised by how hard it is to find a reference for this.

Comment: @IanCampbell I've found that to be true with a lot of abbreviations used in many fields.

Comment: Thank you Ian! It's strange that it's not included in dictionaries... at least in none of those I've searched.

Comment: @Mag As you can see I converted your answer to a comment. This site works a bit differently than discussion forums you may be used to. You should only post answers to questions in the answer box. The way you thank Ian for his answer is by upvoting it and accepting it. You might want to take the [tour] to get a better idea how the site works.

Answer (score 3):

The abbreviation "c/f" in this case means "concern for".

> Given concern for possible hepatic encephalopathy, [we] started lactulose [therapy]